# Is using VisualSVN server + Git clients (using git svn) a good solution for hosting repositories?

Tags: git, git-svn, visualsvn-server

Because I had VisualSVN already set up on Windows 7 as SVN server, and Git can support Git SVN, so will using these two be a good solution

1) for now
2) for the long term?

(that is, as opposed to setting up a Git repo with a machine running ssh daemon, which is non-standard on a PC)

Comment: Setting up git is so simple. At the very least you can just type 'git init' and have a local repo, then look into pushing it out to remotes later. If it was me I'd drop SVN altogether and go with git.

Comment: i think the problem is Windows has no standard ssh... and... TortoiseSVN is still quite good GUI integrated with File Explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this blog post](http://dylanbeattie.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-host-git-in-same-apache-server.html), it looks like git can co-exist happily on a VisualSVN server.  I think probably the only bit you'd need to be wary of is the upgrade - if you separated all the git config stuff into a configuration file and then included it from the main one, you ought to be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I've had trouble with git-svn vs. VisualSVN over https, protected with NTLM credentials. It seems to work aces over http with more usual schemes.

Comment: Thx Olay. I couldn't get HTTPS/NTLM working at all, switched VisualSvn to Subversion authentication, set up a local user and then HTTP worked.